# Android: "Permission Error" on Capture using Camera

Tags: android, local-storage, android-permissions, android-image-capture

In Android the Camera action show a error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity } from ProcessRecord{beb99ec 32121:com.android.hawee/u0a369} (pid=32121, uid=10369) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
```

I request permission on manifest as follows

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And on chooserDialog on click of camera

```
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, Constants.CAMERA_CAPTURE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
                } else {
                    Intent camera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    activity.startActivityForResult(camera, Constants.IMAGE_CAPTURE_CAMERA);
                }
```

On activity

```
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frameContainer);
        fragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

And on Fragment

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == Constants.CAMERA_CAPTURE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Intent camera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(camera, Constants.IMAGE_CAPTURE_CAMERA);
            } else {
                new CommonDialogOK(getActivity(), getString(R.string.Sorry), getString(R.string.Permissions_Not_Granted));
            }
        } else if (requestCode == Constants.PICK_IMAGE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(gallery, Constants.IMAGE_CAPTURE_GALLERY);
            } else {
                new CommonDialogOK(getActivity(), getString(R.string.Sorry), getString(R.string.Permissions_Not_Granted));
            }
        }
    }
```

But on click from ChooserDialog always get above error.
How can i ask permission for write to external and Image capture at same time.

Comment: You don't actually need the `CAMERA` permission to take pictures via `Intent`. However, if you list that permission in the manifest, it will throw that Exception if it's not granted, so as not to confuse users who might manually revoke that permission from your app. You could simply remove that `<uses-permission>` element, and the code for that particular request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If camera n external storage both are required for your app you should `||` them in if condition.

```
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, Constants.CAMERA_CAPTURE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
                } else {
                    Intent camera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    activity.startActivityForResult(camera, Constants.IMAGE_CAPTURE_CAMERA);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
public static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1;
```

in onCreate()

```
private void checkAndroidVersion() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkAndRequestPermissions();

        } 

    }
```

This method

```
private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
        int camera = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        int wtite = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int read = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        if (wtite != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        if (camera != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        }
        if (read != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

then use this

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d("in fragment on request", "Permission callback called-------");
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {

                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();
                // Initialize the map with both permissions
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                // Fill with actual results from user
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                        perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                    // Check for both permissions
                    if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            && perms.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.d("in fragment on request", "CAMERA & WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission granted");
                        // process the normal flow
                        //else any one or both the permissions are not granted
                    } else {
                        Log.d("in fragment on request", "Some permissions are not granted ask again ");
                        //permission is denied (this is the first time, when "never ask again" is not checked) so ask again explaining the usage of permission
//                        // shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return true
                        //show the dialog or snackbar saying its necessary and try again otherwise proceed with setup.
                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                            showDialogOK("Camera and Storage Permission required for this app",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            switch (which) {
                                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                                    checkAndRequestPermissions();
                                                    break;
                                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                                    // proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                        //permission is denied (and never ask again is  checked)
                        //shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return false
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Go to settings and enable permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                            //                            //proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void showDialogOK(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", okListener)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
```

And Finally on button click when u save profile or so

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!checkAndRequestPermissions()) {

            }
            else {
                // do your stuff here
            }

        } else {
            // do your stuff here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**For Checking permission I created a separate class as below:**

```
public class MarshMallowPermission {

public static final int RECORD_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
public static final int EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
public static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 3;
Activity activity;

public MarshMallowPermission(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

public boolean checkPermissionForRecord(){
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean checkPermissionForExternalStorage(){
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean checkPermissionForCamera(){
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void requestPermissionForRecord(){
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)){
       Toast.makeText(activity, "Microphone permission needed for recording. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},RECORD_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

public void requestPermissionForExternalStorage(){
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
        Toast.makeText(activity, "External Storage permission needed. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

public void requestPermissionForCamera(){
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)){
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Camera permission needed. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
 }
```

Then

```
MarshMallowPermission marshMallowPermission = new 
MarshMallowPermission(this);


 public void getPhotoFromCamera() {

if (!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForCamera()) {
    marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForCamera();
} else {
    if (!marshMallowPermission.checkPermissionForExternalStorage()) {
        marshMallowPermission.requestPermissionForExternalStorage();
    } else {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator
                        + getString(R.string.directory_name_corp_chat)
                        + File.separator
                        + getString(R.string.directory_name_images)
        );

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        try {
            mediaFile = File.createTempFile(
                    "IMG_" + timeStamp,  /* prefix */
                    ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                    mediaStorageDir      /* directory */
            );
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mediaFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: incomplete it is , it does not work if i deny the persmissions

Answer (score 0):

The answer needs more upvotes and should be the official answer about permissions with camera, the other answers don't solved the problem on Android 10.

And how we know, the answers/codes that work on new versions works on olders.

Help us to index this answer:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, Constants.CAMERA_CAPTURE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
                } else {
                    Intent camera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    activity.startActivityForResult(camera, Constants.IMAGE_CAPTURE_CAMERA);
                }
```